# Objective-C, having trouble with variables in different methods

Tags: objective-c, xcode, variables

I have a .h file where 2 variables are declared, then I have a .m file with a variety of methods, all of which need to access the 2 variables from the .h file.

Here is the .h file, with the 2 variables paths and documentsDirectory

```
@interface create_textViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;
IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
NSArray *paths;
NSString *documentsDirectory;
```

}

In my .m file, the first method is supposed to initialize the 2 variables, and then the other method is just meant to access them.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
[super loadView];
NSLog(@"viewdidload");
paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

}

```
-(void)toiPad{
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/output.txt", documentsDirectory];
NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", textView.text];
[content writeToFile:name atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
```

}

However, when i put in an NSLog in the toiPad method and try to output the documentsDirectory, the program crashes.

Any advice?  I think I may just been missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine (the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains) doesn't explicitly state it) that `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` returns an autoreleased object, so try:

```
documentsDirectory = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] retain];
```

You'll need to release it in the `dealloc` method, which I assume you're already doing.

Don't bother keeping the `paths` value at all (just call `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` whenever you need it again).